# Check if android app has a newer version on playStore

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-version

I want to know if it is possible to check if the app that the user is running is the latest version that is available at Google PlayStore. I have read some answers and they say that this is not possible, but I see some apps that do this.

Can someone tell me how can I do this? I can see that this is possible.

Comment: Some apps query their own server to check for the latest version available. There's no easy way of doing this through google play services. Some people suggest parsing your Google play store listing page, but that  is not a good method, and might break anytime.

Comment: There's no public API just different work around like check on your server in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the Google Play Services **do not expose such API**.

But you could use a workaround to check for newer versions: a simple request on your serveur could do, parsing the Play Store page could do too etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an api on your server for these kind of operations.

Your api can return values such as currentVersionCode, minVersionCode and an updateMessage.

You can compare your apps version code, currentVersionCode and minVersionCode and show a dialog for nice to update or force update.